# Magento 2.1.3 Installation Error

Tags: installation, magento-2.1.3

I'm trying to install Magento 2.1.3 in my local but there are lots of problem.

[image]

And I am really new and have no idea in Magento and I can't find reliable articles in this new versions error. How do I fix this one?

Comment: Why in Title You wrote Magento 1.9.3? Have you dome compose install / composer update? paste project's main composer.json file

Comment: required files are missing in your magento . pls check them.

Comment: Either your package is not proper or it seems permission issue

Comment: @KonradSiamro The composer thingy worked. Thanks!